# Solving $\log_3x^3 - 4\log_9x - 5\log_{27}x^{1/2} = \log_94$

Tags: logarithms

Having trouble solving this simple logarithm problem:

$$\log_3(x^3) - 4\log_9(x) - 5\log_{27}(x^{1/2}) = \log_9(4)$$

I’ve been stuck as I when I solve it I get an answer of $2$, when the actual solution seems to be $x=64$?

Whilst editing and trying to explain my working I found the error I did. Solution:
$$
\begin{align}
\log_3(x^3) - 4\log_9(x) - 5\log_{27}(x^{1/2}) = \log_9(4)&
\\
\log_3(x^3) - {\log_3{x^4}}/{\log_3(9)} - {\log_3(x^{1/2})^5}/{\log_3(27)} = {\log_3(4)}/{\log_3(9)}&
\\
\log_3(x^3) - {\log_3{x^4}}/{2} - {\log_3(x^{1/2})^5}/{3} = {2\log_3(2)}/{2}&
\\
6\log_3(x^3)/{6} - {3\log_3{x^4}}/{6} - {2\log_3(x^{1/2})^5}/{6} = {\log_3(2)}&
\\
6\log_3(x^3) - {3\log_3{x^4}} - {2\log_3(x^{1/2})^5} = {\log_3(64)}&
\\
\log_3(x^3)^6 - {\log_3(x^4)^3} - {\log_3(x^{1/2})^{10}} = {\log_3(64)}&
\\
\log_3(x^6)- {\log_3(x^{5})} = {\log_3(64)}&
\\
\log_3{x}= {\log_3(64)}&
\end{align}
$$
And since $\log_c(a) = \log_c(b)$, $a=b$, the solution is

$$x=64$$

Apologies if there is a nicer solution, I tried my best!

Comment: Thank you, while trying to edit the formatting and write down my working I actually found the error in my working.

Comment: @bazingachanga consider answering your own question if you've figured it out

Comment: @bazingachanga I agree with B Wang that you should answer your own question. Doing that is encouraged on this site if user figures out the question he or she asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the exponent rule for logarithms, we have
\begin{align*}
3\log _3 x - 4\log _9 x - \frac{5}{2}\log _{27} x = \log _9 4
\end{align*}
and by change of base rule we have
\begin{align*}
3\log _3 x - 4\cdot\frac{\log _3 x}{\log _3 9} - \frac{5}{2}\cdot\frac{\log _3 x}{\log _3 27} = \frac{\log _3 4}{\log _3 9}\\
3\log _3 x - 4\cdot\frac{\log _3 x}{2} - \frac{5}{2}\cdot\frac{\log _3 x}{3} = \frac{\log _3 4}{2}\text{.}
\end{align*}
Simplifying yields
\begin{align*}
\log _3 x &= 3\cdot\log _3 4\\
\log _3 x &= \log _3 (4^3)\\
x &= 4^3=64\text{.}
\end{align*}